# Using C# Contains Method with Repeating Character

Tags: c#, methods, contains, string-comparison

I am wondering why the following method returns `true` since the first string does not contain the text in the `Contains` method parameter in that order:

```
private bool Test()
{
    if(("55.00").Contains("5."))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Do I need to set a `StringComparison` enum? Or is this unrelated?

Comment: 'Contains' method search through all the string and return true if it has the string you provided at any position.

Comment: In what "order" are you referring? "55.00" indeed contains "5." within it. `Contains()` doesn't need to take anything else into account other that that "5." is somewhere within "55.00". It could care less where in the string it is contained.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `StartsWith`? Or `Equals()`?

Answer (score 2):

Actually your string contains 5.
It will search entire string for match, so it will skip first 5 and on 5. it will return true.
Here is MSDN article: [String.Contains Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Okay, I guess I am misunderstanding the method. How would I check if the first string contains those chars in that exact order

Comment: Use String.StartsWith method.

Comment: The String class in general contains many helpful methods that are worth a good look over.

Answer (score 1):

```
Maybe some helpful examples. I think you have Contains confused with StartsWith.
```

[Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

[StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
("55.00").Contains("5.") == true
("55.00").Contains("55.") == true
("55.00").Contains("5.5") == false

("55.00").StartsWith("5.") == false
("55.00").StartsWith("55.") == true
("55.00").StartsWith("5.5") == false
```